# Font Awesome icon alignment inside md-button

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, font-awesome, angular-material

I'm trying to align font awesome icons inside a button so that they are centered in respect to text on a toolbar.  I have the following markup;

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools" md-tall"">
        <h2>
          <span>Icons</span>
        </h2>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button">
          <md-icon md-font-icon="fa-circle" class="fa"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button">
          <md-icon md-font-icon="fa-circle" class="fa fa-lg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
</div>
```

Which produces the following layout;

[image: Mark above as rendered]

`fa-lg` on the second icon makes it look centred although I suspect it is still aligned to the top.  I tried sticking `layout-alignment="center center"` on the `md-button` to no effect.

How can I control the alignment of font awesome icons inside md-buttons and, specifically how can I vertically center these within the toolbar?  Is there a Angular Material way of doing this alignment, or is custom CSS required here?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbjKvP?editors=100)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears to be the 24px fixed height on the `md-icon` element that is messing with icon's vertical alignment. The FontAwesome icon is designed with a dynamic height, so forcing a fixed height on the `md-icon` element isn't compatible; the middle of this element is no longer the middle of the icon. Try overriding this with `height: auto;` and it should work happily, e.g.:

```
md-icon {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: For Angular Material 7.0.4, (latest in November 2018), this did it for me:
`button .mat-icon {
    height: auto;
}`

Answer (score 4):

The height added for md-icon is causing the issue

```
md-icon {    
    height: 24px;    
}
```

You need to add some **extra class** like follows

```
<md-icon md-font-icon="fa-circle" class="fa **fa-md**"></md-icon>
```

and need to **override the height**

```
.fa-md {
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
.md-icon-button .fa-circle {
  font-size: 23px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the latest release of Angular Material (1.1.1) and this problem has gone. Enjoy!

Comment: And I have checked again now (November 2018) , Angular Material 7.0.4 and it's again there... :(